# Create Tree with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, tree

I created these classes in order to create a tree (user hold the root)

```
public class Node
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public Node Parent_Id { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public Node Root { get; set; }
}
```

but the entity framework (code first) doesnt save the parent_id
(in the user class it save the "root" as expected)

when i created the tables manually (databese first) as it should be, the entity framework save the parent id as int and not "Node"

what can i do?

Comment: Why do you call it `Parent_Id` and not simply `Parent`? I haven't used EF in a while but maybe there is some convention for naming your properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not correctly implementing the `ForeignKey` annotation. You would need to do something like this instead:

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

public int ParentID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ParentID")]
public Node Parent { get; set; }
```

This code above will then allow you to have separate `Nodes` that will then be able to have a `Parent` node assigned to them. Each `Node` needs to have its own ID, plus that of its Parent. The `ForeignKey` annotation must point to the Parent's ID, not the Node's.